# How to return a phone number to swift app?

Tags: swift, contacts, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I want to have my user select a phone number for someone in their contacts and I want to return that number to the app so that I can use it for later.  Here is my code for allowing the user to select one of their contacts phone numbers, but when I click a phone number it calls that number (which I don't want to happen) and doesn't return anything to my app.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

var people = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?

func extractABAddressBookRef(abRef: Unmanaged<ABAddressBookRef>!) -> ABAddressBookRef? {
    if let ab = abRef {
        self.view.addSubview(people.view)
        return Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(ab.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    return nil
}

func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
    let multiValue: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue()
    let index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier)
    let phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

    println(phoneNumber)
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you're allowed to read data from another app (e.g. the Contacts app) inside of your app, as per Apple's app [guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/): `2.6: Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected`.

Comment: even if you ask for permission?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution that only show contacts that have phone numbers, and the user has to select a concrete phone number. Your ViewController has to implement `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Here is my code:

```
func checkAuthorization ()
{
    switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus())
    {
        case .NotDetermined:
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue(), 
            { (granted: Bool, error: CFError!) -> Void in
                if (granted)
                {
                    // Access granted, show picker
                    self.showPeoplePicker();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Custom func to show an alert
                    self.showAlertForContactPermission();
                }
            })
            break;

        case .Restricted, .Denied:
            // Custom func to show an alert
            showAlertForContactPermission();
            break;

        case .Authorized:
            // Access granted, show picker
            showPeoplePicker();
            break;
    }
}

func showPeoplePicker ()
{
    // Create picker
    let peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController();
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    // Show only contacts that have phone number
    peoplePicker.displayedProperties = [NSNumber(int: kABPersonPhoneProperty)];
    peoplePicker.predicateForEnablingPerson = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0", argumentArray: nil);

    // User has to select explicity phone number
    peoplePicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(format: "key == 'phoneNumbers'", argumentArray: nil);

    // Present picker
    presentViewController(peoplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier)
{
    // Get name
    let name: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue() as String;

    // Get phone number selected
    let multiValuePhones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property).takeRetainedValue();
    let selectedIndex: CFIndex = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValuePhones, identifier);
    let selectedPhone: String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValuePhones, selectedIndex).takeRetainedValue() as! String;

    // Get only digits
    let digitsArray: [String] = selectedPhone.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet);
    let phoneDigits: String = digitsArray.joinWithSeparator("");

    // Pass info to your func
    saveNewEmployee(name, phoneNumber: phoneDigits);
}
```